# Input values doesnt get display in the browser instead shows blank field

Tags: php, mysql

I just need to insert my form data into mysql database & display it in browser. But, when I fill up the form & click submit , the row gets added but with no data except for ID field which is autoincremented.. even the table in phpmyadmin looks same with the row added & empty fileds.
any suggestions will be highly appreciated...

my html form looks like this,

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Form Input Students Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <form method="POST" action="data_insert_htmlform.php/">
        <tr>
          <td><label for="Name">Name</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="Age">Age</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="age" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="Birth_Date">Birth_Date</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Birth_Date" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="Address"Address</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="address" size="40">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td align="center">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sent">
          </td>
        </tr>
        </form>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and my php code,

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

$database = 'students';
$continued=mysql_connect("localhost" , "root", "");

if(mysql_select_db($database))
echo ("<br><br>connection to the database succeeds");
else
echo ("connection failed");

/*$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$birth_date = $_POST['Birth_date'];
$address = $_POST['address'];*/

$insert = "INSERT INTO students_basicinfo(Name, Age, Birth_Date, Address) VALUES ('{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['age']}' , '{$_POST['Birth_date']}' , '{$_POST['address']}')";

$abc = mysql_query($insert);
if($abc){
    echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
}else{
    echo("<br>Input data is fail");
}

$order = "SELECT * FROM students_basicinfo";
$result = mysql_query($order);

if($result === FALSE) {
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

echo "<table border='1'>";

    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td>".$data[ID]."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$data[Name]."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$data[Age]."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$data[Birth_Date]."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$data[Address]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: remove / from data_insert_htmlform.php/

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_` function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: have you checked the spelling of your field names and $_POST variables. these are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

This issue about `input name case sensitive`

Change `$_POST['Birth_date']` to `$_POST['Birth_Date']` with uppercase `D`

Try following query, this will work.

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO students_basicinfo(Name, Age, Birth_Date, Address) VALUES ('{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['age']}' , '{$_POST['Birth_Date']}' , '{$_POST['address']}')";
```

Comment: Could you show your DB structure? or Your columns names and `insert` values same? For ex: Column name `Name` or `name`?

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
'{$_POST['name']}','{$_POST['age']}' , '{$_POST['Birth_date']}' , '{$_POST['address']}'
```

**with**

```
'".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['age']."' , '".$_POST['Birth_date']."' , '".$_POST['address']."'
```

Comment: do you get `Input data is succeed` message in browser.?

Comment: @bora.dev try adding `spance` between table name `students_basicinfo (`

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td>".$data['ID']."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$data['Name']."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$data['Age']."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$data['Birth_Date']."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$data['Address']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

(Use prepared statements.)

- Dump the statement, in a HTML comment `<!-- ... --->` so you can try it yourself.
- Use `echo mysql_error()` to check for errors.
- I mistrust the date field, DATE? Use '2013-08-31`or '2013-08-31 14_:07` / '2013-08-31T14_:07`.